# How to avoid comparing two different integer types?

Tags: rust

I seems like I am in a catch 22 situation here.

I have this code:

```rust
const MAX u32 = 10;
let vec Vec<String> = vec![String::from("test")];
    
let exceeds = vec.len() > MAX;
```

I get this error:

```
 let res = vec_one.len() < MAX;
                           ^^^ expected `usize`, found `u32`

 help: you can convert an `u32` to `usize` and panic if 
 the converted value wouldn't fit

 let res = vec_one.len() < MAX.try_into().unwrap();
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As far as I understand from the Rust documentation, if the problem of comparing two different integer types occurs, it has a bad smell.

That shouldn't happen.

However, on the one hand **u32** is the **recommended integer type**, if one is not sure which on to take, because the compiler can handle it most efficiently. I use MAX in many places in the code, where I use it for comparisons with other u32 variables and constants. Therefore MAX has to be of u32 type.

On the other hand Rust's Vector instance returns **usize**, which is, again as far as I understand from the documentation, an integer type depending on the underlying architecture.

In this context the help hint:

```
help: you can convert an `u32` to `usize` and panic if 
the converted value wouldn't fit
```

looks to me rather misleading. A situation where the difference of two integer types raises panic should IMHO be avoided by using the proper integer types up front.

The rust help message should come up with a hint how to solve the integer type collision and not with a help which might in the worst case lead to the halt of program execution.

And, to get to the point, how can I resolve the integer type collision in a better way?

Comment: IMO If `MAX` represents for the maximum of a length, size, amount of memory etc., it should be `usize`. If it is also used for other things such that it is reasonable to be `u32`, just use `MAX as _` to cast it.

Comment: "u32 is the recommended integer type, if one is not sure which on to take" => But here you have a good reason to make it an `usize` instead of an `u32`, so use that.

Comment: @Jesper note that this part is about *other* integers which they *also* compare to `MAX`, so it's a justification for `MAX` being an `u32` rather than `usize`: most use-sites are in a `u32` contexts, and few are in a `usize` context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, on the one hand u32 is the recommended integer type, if one is not sure which on to take, because the compiler can handle it most efficiently.

The compiler doesn't really care, it's more a detail of the architecture. u32 is generally a pretty good default because it's handled efficiently on both 32b and 64b architecture, and when sufficient it avoids "wasting" memory on a u64 (or, god forbid, u128).

> On the other hand Rust's Vector instance returns usize, which is, again as far as I understand from the documentation, an integer type depending on the underlying architecture.

It's, specifically, an integer large enough to hold a pointer. So *strictly speaking* it's ABI-related rather than architecture: though the two are *usually* identical, Linux's x32 ABI uses 32b pointers on a 64b architecture.

x32 makes *some* sense because 32b values are handled efficiently on 64b architectures (so there's no loss there) and it saves memory when lots of values are pointers (lower stack use, smaller structures, better cache locality, ...).

> The rust help message should come up with a hint how to solve the integer type collision and not with a help which might in the worst case lead to the halt of program execution.
>
> And, to get to the point, how can I resolve the integer type collision in a better way?

Just don't put in the `unwrap` call?

`try_into` is not magic, it's just a failible conversion, it'll return `Ok(result)` if the conversion succeeds and `Err(...)` if the conversion fails (which would require that the platform's pointers be less than 32b *and* the specific value doesn't fit in a pointer, which seems unlikely).

But I don't really see the point of performing a runtime conversion here, just provide an usize version of `MAX`.

As Rust doesn't have untyped constant `as` is less safe than desirable (and using separate literal risks them drifting apart), so I'd suggest using a trivial macro expanding to the literal (I guess you could even use a macro instead of a constant in the first place but that's a bit meh doc-wise) e.g.

```rust
macro_rules! MAX {
    () => { 500 }
}
const MAX: u32 = MAX!();
const MAXsise: usize = MAX!();
const MAX8: u8 = MAX!();
```

will properly trigger a compilation error on the third definition whereas `const MAX8: u8 = MAX as u8;` would not.

Or you could perform the conversion with `as` and ignore the issue altogether, given the magnitude of your constant's value the risk is basically non-existent (though present if the possibility exists that MAX would ever be larger than... 2^16 probably)

Comment: This is really a great explanation. I like the idea of using a macro a lot.